# Clarification on the definition of a smooth affine scheme over an integral domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
The following is from Bruhat and Tits article *Groupes Reductifs sur un Corps Locale II*.  $A$ is an integral domain.  Here $A$-scheme means "affine $A$-scheme," and $A[\mathfrak X]$ denotes the coordinate ring of $\mathfrak X$.  This is a definition of what it means for an $A$-scheme to be "smooth" (I believe this is how *lisse* is meant to translate).

[image]

I understand being flat and finitely presented.  But I wanted to clarify the last condition about the fibers.  If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $A$, then the fiber $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$ is the $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$-scheme $\mathfrak X \times_{\Spec A} \Spec \kappa(\mathfrak p)$, where $\kappa(\mathfrak p) = A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$.

A geometric point of $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$ is a morphism of schemes $\Spec (k) \rightarrow \mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.  In other words, a geometric point is a point $x$ of $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$, together with an embedding of the residue field of $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$ at $x$ into an algebraically closed field.

What is the definition of a "simple geometric point" of $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$?   If all the geometric points are simple, is this the same as saying that for an algebraic closure $\overline{\kappa(\mathfrak p)}$ of $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$, all the stalks at all the points of the scheme

$$\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p} \times_{\Spec \kappa(\mathfrak p)} \Spec \overline{\kappa(\mathfrak p)}$$

are regular local rings?  Is there any requirement that the $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$-scheme $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p}$ be reduced?  Or geometrically reduced?

Comment: Before trying to read Bruhat-Tits, shouldn't you have a look at some introductory book in algebraic geometry, e.g. Harthshorne's? There you'll find the definition of a smooth morphism (which, of course, is the same as the one used by Bruhat and Tits).

Comment: Hartshorne defines a smooth morphism for schemes of finite type over a field $k$.  Moreover, he defines "smooth of relative dimension $n$," not just smooth, requiring each $\mathfrak X_{\mathfrak p} \times_{\Spec \kappa(\mathfrak p)} \Spec \overline{\kappa(\mathfrak p)}$ to be equidimensional.  Also, I wasn't sure Bruhat-Tits was using standard definitions, so I wanted to clarify what they said.

Comment: Read about smoothness of morphisms between arbitrary schemes in Chapter 2 of *Neron Models*.  Bruhat-Tits give the precise reference to EGA; their definition within their setup is the standard one (and the equivalences to which they refer are all part of the development of the concept, done in EGA and also in that chapter of *Neron Models* modulo some specific input from EGA).